# Analog of Android assets folder for iOS?

Tags: android, ios

I'm learning iOS having come from Android.

In Android there is a special `assets` folder. One puts some files in there during coding and then one is able to access those files as data streams when the program runs.

I wonder if there is a similar mechanism for iOS. All I've read so far was about how to persist data in iOS but that's not exactly what I want.

Comment: Sure there is - just use `NSBundle`, and do your own data reading and writing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually create a folder "assets" and make sure the files in it are included in Build Phases/Copy Bundle Resources. Once done, I can access those as follows:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainbundle] pathForResource:@"picture" ofType:@"png"];
....
```